# "Partner you" vs. "partner with you"

Tags: grammaticality, transitive-verbs

Can I say for instance *dynamic enough to partner you in facing new* or must it be *partner with you*

I'm specifically asking whether you can say *partner you* as opposed to *partner with you*.

Here's an example; *Opportunities and innovations often mean new legislation. We're a team of lawyers with expertise and experience, dynamic enough to partner you in facing new hurdles*.

Comment: I think we need more information; neither of them particularly make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under its entry for *partner*, NOAD says:

> verb [ trans. ]
> be the partner of : *young farmers who partnered Isabel to the village dance*.
> • [ intrans. ] associate as partners : *I never expected to partner with a man like you*.

That transitive definition seems to imply you could say *partner you*.

[OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=partner) offers a verb definition with a brief yet similar example construct:

> ▸ verb:  act as a partner (*"Astaire partnered Rogers"*)

It does sound odd to me, though.  I tried looking for usages in Google books, but couldn't find one; the search returns too many "false positives," like these:

> As an equal **partner, you** must be reliable.
>
> Although it is no guarantee that a person you meet through mutual friends will turn out to be the **partner you** want, a socially integrated person is far more likely to be a partner capable of entering into a healthy relationship than a socially isolated person.
>
> Now you're not just annoyed; you're angry with your **partner. You** begin to separate yourself from them and erect an emotional barrier.

As Gulliver said in his comment, we might be able to offer more help if you expounded more on an example usage.

Comment: [try this search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22partner+you+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22partner+him+to%22&oq=%22partner+him+to%22&gs_l=serp.3...13859.17857.0.18128.11.11.0.0.0.10.1754.5978.2-3j4j1j8-2.10.0...0.0...1c.1.NX860sd3MXA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=3981c3038a570d78&bpcl=35243188&biw=1280&bih=933) Not many hits, I admit, but it's a real thing.

Comment: @Matt: Nice! As I suspected: rare, but acceptable.